# What is the process called?

Tags: java

The process by which Java is able to determine which method to invoke when methods have
been overridden.

I have this sentence and I would like to find out what the process is called

Comment: Overriding? Polymorphism? Object oriented programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java and other object-oriented programming languages, method overriding is a feature that allows a subclass or child class to provide a specific implementation of a method that is already provided by one of its super-classes or parent classes.

Method overriding is one of the ways in which Java supports **Runtime Polymorphism**. The process you are looking for is **Dynamic method dispatch**. It's the mechanism by which a call to an overridden method is resolved at run time, rather than compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about **Method Lookup**